# JWT - how to send jwt token in every request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, jwt

First, I may be wrong/incorrect in this topic. In a project, I've api gateway in `nodejs`. From client request is being sent in following way:

```
async _submit() {
    this._disabled = true;
    try {
      const user = await api({
        endpoint: '/identity/login',
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
          email: this._data.email,
          password: this._data.password,
        },
      });
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      // window.location.href = "/apps";
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('ERROR!!!', err);
    } finally {
      console.log('finally!!!');
    }
  }
```

This works fine. It sends the request to gateway. Gets the proper response. Stores the response object in `localStorage`. Here, in a response there isn't any authentication property that I can use in future api calls.
In addition to the response, `jwt` cookie (httponly) is being set.

Now, when I redirect to "/apps" I would like to check whether user is authenticated or not before making any other request to gateway. For this, as per my knowledge, I need to send token in every request being sent to gateway.

As token is stored in `httponly cookie`, I can't read the value.

**How do I authenticate user/request once `jwt` token is being set ?**

Comment: That is why there are so many different open source frameworks to solve such issues and make development ease. Anyway how about if you send token as a query string to `/apps` route and then get that token from the url and use it on `apps` page?

Comment: @null it's `httponly` cookie. I can't read it on client.

Comment: Why dont you store it in localStorage etc.

Comment: If the token is already in the cookie, shouldn't it be sent automatically when you make your requests?